# bash: Executing $0 when it is the result of a process redirection

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a script [on GitHub](https://github.com/jamesqo/sinister/blob/master/sinister) that is normally executed as the result of a process redirection, like so:

```
sh <(curl -sSL http://git.io/sinister)
```

The script itself may require root privileges if it's not being run from Windows, so I have added the following lines of code to re-execute itself as root if needed:

```
on_windows()
{
    uname | grep -q '[CYGWIN|MINGW|MSYS]'
}

if ! on_windows && [ "$USER" != 'root' ]; then
    exec sudo "$0"
fi
```

However, this does not seem to be working smoothly with the process redirection. Running `sh -x` results in this:

```
(trusty)james@localhost:~$ sh -x <(curl -sSL http://git.io/sinister)
+ set -e
+ ...
+ on_windows
+ grep -q [CYGWIN|MINGW|MSYS]
+ uname
+ [ james != root ]
+ exec sudo /dev/fd/63
sudo: /dev/fd/63: command not found
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: This is not the cause of your immediate problem, but the regular expression `'[CYGWIN|MINGW|MSYS]'` looks for a single character anywhere in the output which is one of `C`, `Y`, `G`, `|`, `M`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156088

You can try the following: Store the result of the `curl` command in a temporary file and execute this file. Like so:

```
curl -sSL http://git.io/sinister > file.temp
chmod u+x file.temp
./file.temp
```